# How can I find out what sort of creative opportunities a company offers?

Tags: job-search, motivation, learning

Many jobs claim to offer *intellectual fulfillment*, *problem-solving opportunities*, or *freedom to use creative decision-making* to steer one's own work. Yet in my experience, few jobs actually offer this.

I've been conducting a job search for about 8 months now, and I've rejected a few late stage opportunities specifically because it appeared like a similar situation as my current role. Recruiters and hiring managers go out of their way to talk about all the great innovative things they do and all the interesting problem-solving opportunities there will be. Yet when I press for more details, it becomes very clear that that I won't be challenged, won't be given any discretion over the direction of my own work, etc.

I am at a loss about how to combat this problem.

What sort of questions can I ask during an interview to find out if a company really does provide these kinds of creative decision-making opportunities as opposed to ones that are just trying to use buzzwords to attract good employees?

Comment: Depending on your physical location there may not be any jobs that are not ordinary business problems. Generaly only the top 1% of the top 1% really end up working on what you are looking for.

Comment: I believe that I am comfortably within the top 1% of the top 1%, at least in terms of education, awards, publications, and the actual work I have produced on the job. And even given that, it's still the case that 99+% of what I'm asked to do is not interesting. Unfortunately, my preferences are more or less intrinsically set up such that this is unacceptable to me. I've tried for a long time to "just be OK with it" and it's clear to me, from a cognitive health point of view, that I am not physically capable of that.

Comment: To clarify: I think that's a *detrimental* aspect of my personality, not some kind of long-suffering but altruistically positive thing. If I could take a pill that made me content with mind-numbing, boring stuff, I would. It would be better for me across the board. But in years of effort, I've found no way to remain happy enough in a situation like that to be capable of tolerating it for more than about 2 years.

Comment: There are many jobs that "rot your brain". That's why you're paid to do them instead of doing them voluntarily. Factory work and many minimum wage jobs come to mind. If you aren't happy with your job, your best bet is to find one you will be happy at. Either happy with the work you do, or happy with the wage you make, or happy with the people you work with. That said, I'm not sure I see a specific question in here. Can you [edit] your question to try and clarify exactly what you are trying to find an answer to?

Comment: [Related question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/13593/2322).

Comment: I edited to hopefully make my request for concrete steps more clear.

Comment: While you're judging a job it is also judging you, in much the same way that an interview is a two way street. There are some types of job that might not be especially mentally stimulating but if you find yourself constantly unemployed or unhappy in your work, and yet rejecting roles because "they rot the brain" then you may need to re-set your personal expectations. There's an element of "make-work" or "monotony" in every job. Even if you work for yourself there will still be taxes to do. I'm sure even the Queen of the UK looks at her desk diary and says "not *this* again!" on some days.

Comment: @EMS I hope you don't mind, but I've significantly shorted the question in an attempt to keep it focused on the single question you clarified with your edit. I'm going to vote to reopen it, however it will need some other votes from the community to get reopened. If I've changed your question too much, feel free to [edit] it further or to roll back my changes. Thanks :)

Comment: I don't mind the shortening, but the last paragraph is not exactly right. I am not trying to solicit help on how to determine if a company just pays lip service to innovation / fulfilling intellectual work. I believe it's not too hard to figure that out. I am more asking: given than so many companies only offer brain-rotting work, how does one efficiently locate companies that *do* offer genuine opportunities for fulfilling work? Once I'm at the stage of asking them questions myself, I can usually tell pretty easily, which has led to a lot of stressful wasted time on my part.

Comment: @RobM Of course every job has ups and downs. I am not asking for a job that is *solely* comprised of the "fun stuff." I'm talking about going from a job where literally 0% of the work is creative or fulfilling to a job where maybe 40% is creative and fulfilling. I cannot even find something remotely close to that. So I think you are using a false dilemma here... the choice is not between "all fun" vs. "all boring stuff." I just a want a reasonable compromise between them.

Comment: @EMS Unfortunately I don't think there is any good way to tell prior to talking to the company, unless you can find an employee of the company who works in a related role and are able to ask them.

Comment: @ems you come across as only wanting to do the best parts of the job, even if that's not your intention. I've been in a couple of roles where I've essentially defined what the job is... after I showed that I could do my share of the day to day grind and grew enough trust from my managers in my work ethos that they were prepared to trust that whatever I wanted to do would be to the good of the employer.

Comment: @RobM I've not encountered employers who act that way, even after I spend years demonstrating that I will roll up the sleeves and work hard to succeed at the parts that I don't like.

Comment: @EMS What do you do that will be profitable to a company?  Find a company that does that.

Comment: All of the companies that purport to do it don't actually do it. It's a homo-hypocritus problem. It would be genuinely profitable but fails for political reasons, yet serves as the basis for attracting top talent. Most of my peers feel exactly the same way but have just made peace with doing boring jobs to service their life expenses. I seem to be genetically tuned to feel very differently about it than they do, and very differently than many people here as well. I suppose the whole thread is just: unusual preferences are painful and expensive but if they are intrinsic you can't avoid it.

Comment: Many companies absolutely do intellectually challenging problem-solving work (I'll assume you are in software development): Apple; Google; Microsoft; many startups in the fields of natural language; security; wearable devices; robotics; and so on. Have you tried these companies? What was your problem with them?

Comment: Yes, I have tried these. They generally do not actually do the work they claim. My area of expertise is machine learning and I live in the Boston area. I've been searching the local job market for 8 months, and have had late stage interviews and offers from places similar to the ones you mention. It's generally just marketing fluff. The real work is always super boring and work agendas tend to be dictated by people looking to retain political control over products, not looking to genuinely innovate better solutions. Start-ups are often worst offenders, especially if looking for a quick sale.

Comment: I would guess your best bet is to create your own startup. Of course you still will have to figure out what is interesting work and how to sell it to people or it won't be in business for long.  Companies exist to make money not to make people happy in their creativity. If you don't like that then create your own company and see how fast it goes bankrupt.  That boring stuff is what sells widgits.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think questions can reliably determine this.

Two thinks you can rely on to a point are:

## Your gut feeling

If you feel like they are trying to lull you and wouldn't hold up their end, don't take the position.

Only take it if you feel really good about it.

## Your contract

There are certain things you can have put into a contract if they're important to you. Some examples that I know:

- special leave for courses and certifications
- some budget for job related educational literature
- certain responsibilities for projects
- free time for your own projects (see google's famous 20% rule)

Comment: I absolutely agree with this. Although, I am a quantitative person so I don't like just trusting my gut (especially given the myriad cognitive biases which I surely exhibit as any person would). The point about the contract is spot on. And in 8 months of search, doing greater than 50 phone screens, greater than 20 on-site interviews, greater than 15 multi-round interviews, and rejecting 4 distinct final offers, I know that so far, there have been zero jobs in the applied statistics / scientific computation / machine learning space in Boston that could pass my "gut feeling" test.